# How to bake glass material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency, texture-baking

I am trying to bake the texture of a simple bottle using cycles. The node set up is shown in the image. The transparency never bakes on to the image and always shows up as opaque.

[image]

I want to export the mesh and the image.

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Manually setting the alpha using the compositor (or just changing the image opacity in gimp) would be the easiest solution - I think the opacity would be consistent anyway.

Comment: This isn't quite possible, as the "transparency" of the glass shader is not alpha transparency, but path traced refraction. You should be able to use a holdout shader to get a result as close as I think you could hope for, but probably not what you are expecting (See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12100/599), but this doesn't seem to work at all when baking..

Comment: The holdout shader only works to render it right in blender. But the baking issue is still remains unresolved.

Comment: I think that baking only works for lighting on solid surfaces, as it is used for textures. The nature of glass makes it impossible to bake it in this way, as when you move the camera the light being transmitted through is different, which can not be recorded in an image. This could theoretically be implemented in future, but is not currently supported.