# Cycles viewport rendering of image planes with alpha channel problem

Tags: transparency, blend-modes

I want to render my simple animation only in the viewport,
and I cannot ignore this problem any more.
whenever i deselect imported image planes with alpha transparencies (in this case, as a light effect), they also mask out and hides every object behind it.
this is not much of a problem for other "alpha graphics" when they don't contain any semi transparent pixels with them but the case with this set up is just not acceptable

---

(this image's blend mode is set to add)
*i set images with no semi-transparency with alpha clip*
[image: image with alpha channel selected]
[image: image blend mode set to add]

once deselected :|

[image: image with alpha channel deselected]

my simple setup for the light effect with controlable fadein-out (fac)
[image: node for light fx]

[image]

the one at the top has semi-transparency set to blendmode:alpha blend,
the one in the bottom is actually a monochrome picture set to blendmode:add

PS. how does one do this light effect for BI and BGE as well?

advance thanks for helping!

Comment: are the two planes [overlapping](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40698/2816) on the y axis ?Also can you upload a *.blend* file with the images packed?I can't reproduce this effect you are having to come up with an answer..

Comment: the glow and the wall? no, they are not