# how to add transparent text and shapes to a movie?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have read [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/can-i-easily-add-text-to-a-movie) on how to add text to a movie.

Folowing the tuto I succeded to also add some rectangular plane below the text, all on my movie in the VSE.

But, my question is : how to alow the text or the shape to be transparent over the movie ? I would like my plane shape to be something like 30% alpha. Alghough I did the setting in the 3D vue, the shape appears no transparent in the VSE.

The tuto gave some settings that seem to avoir transparency.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can set your Strips Blend Type in its Properties (hit *N*) to Alpha Over and then change its opacity.

Comment: This impacts the whole scence. What about having the text not transparent and the plane shape transparent ? Maybe his is an impossible wish...

Comment: Possible overlap with the solution from http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/how-to-render-semi-transparent-objects-with-transparent-background-as-a-png-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
In fact the tuto [I talked about](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/can-i-easily-add-text-to-a-movie) misdirected me.

So I simplified, to add shapes and text over a movie (as an animated title), and allow them to have transparency over the movie, it is really simple :

1/ Go in 3D view

2/ Create some text and/or shape and animate it.

3/ In the global rendering panel, for "Shading" set Alpha > transparent

4/ Give some material to the text and the shape and !! it is possible to set here transparency : Alpha 50 % for example !! This is what I needed !

5/ Then, go back in the VSE, click add>scene and select the scene (it is possible to create many scenes).

6/ Finally, right click on the inserted scene and in the properties panel (N) set : Edit strip> Blend > Alpha Over (instead of Cross).

Result : text and shape render and animate well over the movie.

In fact, this is what I did not from the other post :

- set shadeless
- switch the shading from Multitexture, to GLSL.

I hope it will serve someone someday...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Blender VSE strips have a parameter called Opacity.  It is the 4th line in the N-panel for me.  If you set that on your overlays (and make sure the Blend mode is set to something sane like Alpha Over instead of Replace) it probably will accomplish what you want.

Comment: And i just now noticed Samoth's comment that said the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I know this parameter. But it has effect on the whole scene. What about having the text not transparent and the plane shape transparent ?

Comment: You'll probably need DS89's solution combined with http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/how-to-render-semi-transparent-objects-with-transparent-background-as-a-png-with .  Not knowing about the Render settings > Film > Transparent checkbox is a pretty common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your node setup?

[image: Transparent result]

Here's something that's probably more similar to what you want.

[image: transparency with multiply]

Slide the factor to '1.000' to get full transparency or type in any value such as '0.3' to get less.